# Copy table values to another table with + column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, A and B, and I need to copy the values from A into B. I tried an sql like this:

```
insert into B (UPDATE_FILE, RUN_DATE, CREATED_DATE) 
SELECT UPDATE_FILE, RUN_DATE from A
```

My problem is that table A did not have created_date column while in B the created_date is not nullable. How can I set a default value to created_date or the current time with this sql? I am using SQLiteStudio 3.0.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
insert into B (UPDATE_FILE, RUN_DATE, CREATED_DATE) 
SELECT UPDATE_FILE, RUN_DATE,now() from A
```

It will insert current date in the "CREATED_DATE" column.

Answer (score 0):

**You can pass a default date... like this**

insert into B (UPDATE_FILE, RUN_DATE, CREATED_DATE) 
SELECT UPDATE_FILE, RUN_DATE,'any Date' from A